# How do I fetch rows from one Entity based on their relationship to another?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have two entities:
Track:
     createdDate

Location:
     altitude
     ...(7 more attributes in 'Location')

Track has one attribute 'createdDate' with a To-Many to Location.

I need to select back all locations where the Track.createdDate == "whatever-date-i-want"
(In SQL it's a join, easy to do.)
Here I'm not sure what to do...

The Location entity does NOT have a 'createdDate' attribute since I believe foreignKeys are handled by CoreData itself. Data is going in perfectly if I view the sqlite file, I can see a bunch of locations for every one track (as the GPS plops them into CD)

I am guessing it's a special way of doing a predicate. I tried this following line to no avail:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(Track.createdDate == %@)", currentTrack.createdDate];
```

but it didn't work. I also tried putting a property in there like so:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) Track *lookupTrack;
```

and trying:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(lookupTrack.createdDate == %@)", currentTrack.createdDate];
```

also to no avail... ideas? Thanks

EDIT:
just now I tried:

**NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(ANY track.createdDate == %@)", currentTrack.createdDate];**

which gave me the error 'keypath createdDate not found in entity '

AND

**NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(ALL track.createdDate == %@)", currentTrack.createdDate];**

which gave me the error 'Unsupported predicate (null)'

EDIT:
here are some screenshots
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologise... it was my sort ...

I had

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdDate" ascending:NO];
```

where it should have been

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"track.createdDate" ascending:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the *"inverse relationship"* from "Location" to "Track" in the 
Core Data model inspector.

- Define a to-one relationship from "Location" to "Track", call it "track".
- Define "track" as inverse relationship to the to-many relationship from "Track"
  to "Location".

Then the predicate would be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"track.createdDate == %@", currentTrack.createdDate]
```

Comment: @Beau: What is the inverse relationship called? Do you use it in the predicate? Is the inverse relationship to-one or to-many?

Comment: added screenshots above

Comment: @Beau: That looks correct. But then the predicate from my answer should work.

Comment: doesn't tho... CD IS so twerky

Comment: Yes, same as listed above.

Comment: 'keypath createdDate not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Location id=1>' when I try:NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(track.createdDate == %@)", currentTrack.createdDate];
    [

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39096/discussion-between-martin-r-and-beau)